# How to get the searched text in v-client-table?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-tables-2

I am trying to create a custom column filter in v-client-table.

https://codepen.io/pydev/pen/BaZKgpR

```
    options: {
      dateColumns: ['birth_date'],
      filterable: ['name','manufacturer', 'birth_date'],  
      headings: {
        name: 'Name',
        birth_date: 'Birth Date',
        age: 'Age',
      },
```

I am trying to make some tweaks to the 'Name' column filter.

- I tried to get the text entered in the 'Name' search field so that I can mimic a customFilter, but unable to find a way to get the searched text.
- I am strictly looking to keep the search box in the column filter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vue-tables` component does not expose API to read the filter value. It dispatches `vue-tables.filtered` event but with just resulting items matching the query as the parameter. Query itself is not reachable. [Here are the details](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables/tree/bd0172a8a42448a4a341f708249f0a4b04b0c6a5#events)

It is worth raising an issue to the author maybe, to extend this event with the `query` as well.

You can still hack the component, and use this event to know when the value of the input is changed like this (`ready` method). But it's obviously very hacky.

```js
  ready: function() {
    // ... other things
    this.$on('vue-tables.filtered', function(event) {
      console.log(this.$el.querySelector('.VueTables__name-filter-wrapper input').value);
    });

  },
```